# Using "isEqual" to compare a boolean type

Tags: objective-c

How can I compare a boolean return soap with boolean value, like "false". I have tried these:

```
if ([id isEqual:false]){
        [self ShowMsg];
    }
```

or this

```
if ([id isEqualToValue:false]) {
        [self ShowMsg];
    }
```

or this

```
if (id == false){  
        [self ShowMsg];
    }
```

The "id" information comes from a Soap request, example:

```
SoapRequest* _request = [SoapRequest create: _target action: _action service: self soapAction: @"http://tempuri.org/MyClass" postData: _envelope deserializeTo: @"Boolean"];
```

However, when I make these comparation they don't work anyway.

Thanks.

Comment: What does the `SoapRequest` class look like?  Also, don't use `==` or `!=` with bool constants...

Comment: You don't actually have a variable named `id` in Objective-C code, do you? Does that even compile? `id` is a type in Objective-C.

Comment: Thanks for reply. No, I have used "id" like a example, however the name of variable is another one.

Comment: id is an keyword (Generic datatype) you can not place variable name as a id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bool value is primitive value. In objective-C it have YES and NO.
If you want to compare Bool value in then for true condition you code should be,

```
if ([yourServerBoolValue boolValue]){ //Compiler understand  [yourServerBoolValue boolValue] == YES
        [self ShowMsg];
}
```

for checking NO /false condition

```
if (![yourServerBoolValue boolValue]){ //Compiler understand  [yourServerBoolValue boolValue] == NO
            [self ShowMsg];
    }
```

Comment: Thanks fro your reply. It does not work. this is the complete class:
- (void) ExampleHandler: (id) retorno {

if (![retorno YES]) {
        
        [self ShowMsg];
    }
}

Comment: Your code is not the same as @Reformer's answer. Try `if (![retorno boolValue]) ...`.

Comment: I have tried, but the error is: "Expected identifier":

if (![retorno YES]) {
        
        [self ExibeAlertaDeEmailJaCadastrado];
    }

Or:

if (![retorno true]) {
        
        [self ExibeAlertaDeEmailJaCadastrado];
    }

Comment: So Sorry! Ok now I have got the ideia! Perfect! It have worked. Even if I set my return request to "NSString"...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Bool's are primitive in Obj-C, to compare them, simply use the `==` operator or the `!=` operator, here are some samples:

```
if(booleanName == YES)
{
     //Do something, the boolean is true
}

if(booleanName != YES)
{
     //Do something, the boolean is false
}
```

Comment: I have tried using this example, but it does not compile, the error is "Implicit conversion of int to Id is disallowed with ARC". The return that i have received form my soap web service is @"false"...

Comment: This is the complete one:

- (void) ExampleHandler: (id) retorno { if (retorno != YES) { [self ShowMsg]; } }